# Can two Windows 7 share partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a bit of an odd question: If I install two Windows 7 (one for 32-bits and one for 64-bits) can they share the same partition?

I want to do it because I want to have both OS but I don't want to have to copy the data from one to another. e.g. if I download a file on the 64-bit OS I want to be able to access it from 32-bit without having to copy/duplicate it there and have 2 separate versions on my hard drive.

Comment: Even if they don't share a partition, you'd still be able to access data on the other's partition.

Comment: @Gabe Really? how?

Comment: C:\Users\<username>

Comment: Just set the permissions so that "Everyone" has access.

Comment: Oh wow I feel silly. I had no idea it was that simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, why do you need separate 32-bit and 64-bit OSes?

Comment: @gronostaj Mostly from a reverse-engineering standpoint. OllyDbg doesn't work as it should for me on 64-bit **at all** (tested with VirtualBox) and CE's debugger gets detected in nearly any case.

Comment: Or simply use a third common data partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible with [NT 6.x fast installer](http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/), but it may not be a perfect solution. Intalling two OSes on one partition has some other implications like shared *Program Files* folders (which won't work as expected). Maybe you should simply create a junction to the profile directory on another partition.

Comment: Junction? what does that mean? can you elaborate?

Comment: Directory junction is a mechanism that allows you to "connect" one directory or file with different names on different drives and in different paths. You can read about it on Wikipedia or google it. Junctions can be created with a tool called `mklink`.